# How to configure ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver so that ControllerAdvice class is detected?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

From this api doc of [ResponseEntityExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html), it says -

> Note that in order for an @ControllerAdvice subclass to be detected,
> ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver must be configured.

What kind of configuration is being referred here. Can someone provide more details or any code regarding this.

I am using spring boot 2.x.

Comment: You don't need to do anything with Spring Boot that is configured automatically, unless you disabled auto configuration for web components.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the @ControllerAdvice to handle your exceptions, you don't need to configure anything.

Example :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    ResponseEntity<String> importErrorExceptionHandler(NotFoundException e) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
                .body(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

But, if you want to override a base method out of the ResponseEntityExceptionHandler and provide your own custom implementation, you can read this documentation : https://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api